# Why there are C files in Symfony2 repository?

Tags: php, c, symfony

I am wondering the purpose of these two files here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/search?l=c

- src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Resources/ext/php_symfony_debug.h
- src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Resources/ext/symfony_debug.c

why a PHP framework would have C code in its repository?

Comment: Looks like it's a special PHP extension to help with debugging the framework itself, providing a handful of new PHP functions

Comment: thanks @MarkBaker got it here: https://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/2.8/src/Symfony/Component/Debug/Resources/ext